# Groovy Regex illegal Characters

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a Groovy script that converts some very poorly formatted data into XML. This part works fine, but it's also happily passing some characters along that aren't legal in XML. So I'm adding some code to strip these out, and this is where the problem is coming from.

The code that isn't compiling is this:

`def illegalChars = ~/[\u0000-\u0008]|[\u000B-\u000C]|[\u000E-\u001F]|[\u007F-\u009F]/`

What I'm wondering is, why? What am I doing wrong here? I tested this regex in http://regexpal.com/ and it works as expected, but I'm getting an error compiling it in Groovy:

> [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] line 23:26: unexpected char: 0x0

The line above is `line 23`. The surrounding lines are just variable declarations that I haven't changed while working on the regex.

Thanks!

Update:
The code compiles, but it's not filtering as I'd expected it to.
In regexpal I put the regex:

> [\u0000-\u0008\u000B-\u000C\u000E-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]

and the test data:

```
name='lang'>E</field><field name='title'>CHEMICAL IMMUNOLOGY AND ALLERGY</field></doc>
<doc><field name='page'>72-88</field><field name='shm'>3146.757500</field><field 
name='pubc'>47</field><field name='cs'>1</field><field name='issue'>NUMBER</field>
<field name='auth'>Dvorak, A.</field><field name='pub'>KARGER</field><field  
 name='rr'>GBP013.51</field><field name='issn'>1660-2242</field><field 
name='class1'>TS</field><field name='freq'>S</field><field 
name='class2'>616.079</field><field name='text'>Subcellular Localization of the 
Cytokines, Basic Fibroblast Growth Factor and Tumor Necrosis Factor- in Mast 
Cells</field><field name='id'>RN170369808</field><field name='volume'>VOL 85</field>
<field name='year'>2005</field><field name='lang'>E</field><field 
name='title'>CHEMICAL IMMUNOLOGY AND ALLERGY</field></doc><doc><field   
name='page'>89-97</field><field name='shm'>3146.757500</field><field 
name='pubc'>47</field><field name='cs'>1</field><field
```

It's a grab from a file with one of the illegal characters, so it's a little random. But regexpal highlights only the illegal character, but in Groovy it's replacing even the '<' and '>' characters with empty strings, so it's basically annihilating the entire document.

The code snippet:

```
    def List parseFile(File file){
    println "reading File name: ${file.name}"
    def lineCount = 0
    List data = new ArrayList()

    file.eachLine {
        String input ->
        lineCount ++
        String line = input
        if(input =~ illegalChars){
            line = input.replaceAll(illegalChars, " ")
        }
        Map document = new HashMap()
        elementNames.each(){
            token ->
            def val = getValue(line, token)
            if(val != null){
                if(token.equals("ISSUE")){
                    List entries = val.split(";")
                    document.putAt("year",entries.getAt(0).trim())
                    if(entries.size() > 1){
                        document.putAt("volume", entries.getAt(1).trim())
                    }
                    if(entries.size() > 2){
                        document.putAt("issue", entries.getAt(2).trim())
                    }
                } else {
                    document.putAt(token, val)
                }
            }
        }
        data.add(document)
    }

    println "done"
    return data
}
```

I don't see any reason that the two should behave differently; am I missing something?

Again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK here's my finding:

```
>>> print "XYZ".replaceAll(
       /[\\u0000-\\u0008\\u000B\\u000C\\u000E-\\u001F\\u007F-\\u009F]/,
       "-"
    )

---

>>> print "X\0YZ".replaceAll(
       /[\u0000-\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]/,
       "-"
    )

X-YZ

>>> print "X\0YZ".replaceAll(
       "[\\u0000-\\u0008\\u000B\\u000C\\u000E-\\u001F\\u007F-\\u009F]",
       "-"
    )

X-YZ
```

In other words, my `\\uNNNN` answer within `/pattern/` is WRONG. What happens is that `0-\` becomes part of the range, and this includes `<`, `>` and all capital letters.

The `\\uNNNN` only works in `"pattern"`, not in `/pattern/`.

I will edit my official answer based on comments to this "answer".

#### Related questions

- [How to escape Unicode escapes in Groovy’s /pattern/ syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241933/how-to-escape-unicode-escapes-in-groovys-pattern-syntax)

Comment: Changing the type of string worked, so my script is now working as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
line 23:26: unexpected char: 0x0
```

This error message points to this part of the code:

```
def illegalChars = ~/[\u0000-...
12345678901234567890123
```

It looks like for some reason the compiler doesn't like having Unicode 0 character in the source code. That said, you should be able to fix this by doubling the slash. This prevents Unicode escapes at the source code level, and let the regex engine handle the unicode instead:

```
def illegals = ~/[\\u0000-\\u0008\\u000B\\u000C\\u000E-\\u001F\\u007F-\\u009F]/
```

Note that I've also combined the character classes into one instead of as alternates. I've also removed the range definition when they're not necessary.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

---

#### On doubling the slash

Here's the relevant quote from [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> Unicode escape sequences such as `\u2014` in Java source code are processed as described in [JLS 3.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#100850). Such escape sequences are also implemented directly by the regular-expression parser so that Unicode escapes can be used in expressions that are read from files or from the keyboard. Thus the strings `"\u2014"` and `"\\u2014"`, while not equal, compile into the same pattern, which matches the character with hexadecimal value `0x2014`.

To illustrate, in Java:

```
System.out.println("\n".matches("\\u000A")); // prints "true"
```

However:

```
System.out.println("\n".matches("\u000A"));
// DOES NOT COMPILE!
// "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"
```

This is because `\u000A`, which is the newline character, is escaped in the second snippet at the source code level. The source code essentially becomes:

```
System.out.println("\n".matches("
"));
// DOES NOT COMPILE!
// "String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"
```

This is not a legal Java source code.

Comment: Thank you -- the code and the explanation explained a lot!

And it does compile, so it seems like I'm in good shape.

Thanks!

Comment: @Rakesh: If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check-mark icon.

Comment: Oops -- newbie mistake... done :)
Should I move the 2nd part to a separate question?

Comment: @Rakesh: no need for a new question just yet, we can try to figure it out on this question for now. You can unaccept for now so people can see that you still have issues. If you can provide a complete snippet that reproduces the problem, that'd also be nice. @Alan: do you have insight on Rakesh's follow-up?

Comment: I'll put up the entire snippet momentarily. I was doing a bit of cleanup so that it would be easier to read, as well as doing some experimenting to try to solve this issue, as opposed to just waiting for the community to solve it for me :)
@polygenlubricants -- I'm wondering about the slashes now also, because I tried them in regexpal and it selected every non-alphabetical character -- except the one that I'm trying to strip.

Comment: Is there a way to put raw XML (well, in this case SGML, but it ought to work the same way) text up? I have an SGML snippet with illegal characters, but it doesn't look that way after publishing.

Comment: @Alan, @Rakesh: I've taken the initiative to splinter this issue to a different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241933/how-to-use-unicode-escapes-in-groovys-pattern-syntax

Comment: @Rakesh: for now, try using `"pattern"` instead of `/pattern/`. So `"[\\u0000-\\u0008\\u000B\\u000C\\u000E-\\u001F\\u007F-\\u009F]"`. Tell me if that works.

Comment: @polygenlubricants -- I'll follow it on the other thread, and check this one again, since the first question DID get answered here :)

I'll also try the regular quotes, and see what happens.

Thanks!

Comment: @Rakesh: Also try with `\0` instead of `\u0000`, no double slashing.

Comment: Switching to a double-quoted string ended up doing the trick, so the script is working now.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this Regular Expression to remove unicode char from the string :

```
/*\\u([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])/
```

Answer (score 0):

try

def illegalChars = ~/[\u000**1**-\u0008]|[\u000B-\u000C]|[\u000E-\u001F]|[\u007F-\u009F]/`

Comment: This will change the pattern so that it will NOT match `\u0000`, when that is clearly the intent.