# How to escape Unicode escapes in Groovy's /pattern/ syntax

Tags: unicode, groovy

The following Groovy commands illustrate my problem.

First of all, this works ([as seen on lotrepls.appspot.com](http://lotrepls.appspot.com/?language=Groovy&script=%20%22%5Cn%22.matches%28%22%5Cu000A%22%29;?language=Groovy&script=print%20%22a%22.matches%28/%5Cu0061/%29)) as expected (note that `\u0061` is `'a'`).

```
>>> print "a".matches(/\u0061/)

true
```

Now let's say that we want to match `\n`, using the Unicode escape `\u000A`. The following, using `"pattern"` as a string, behaves as expected:

```
>>> print "\n".matches("\u000A");

Interpreter exception: com.google.lotrepls.shared.InterpreterException:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed,
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway
@ line 1, column 21. 1 error
```

This is expected because in Java at least, Unicode escapes are processed early ([JLS 3.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.3)), so:

```
print "\n".matches("\u000A")
```

really is the same as:

```
print "\n".matches("
")
```

The fix is to escape the Unicode escape, and let the regex engine process it, as follows:

```
>>> print "\n".matches("\\u000A")

true
```

Now here's the question part: how can we get this to work with the Groovy `/pattern/` syntax instead of using string literal?

Here are some failed attempts:

```
>>> print "\n".matches(/\u000A/)

Interpreter exception: com.google.lotrepls.shared.InterpreterException:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed,
Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found '(' @ line 1, column 19.
1 error

>>> print "\n".matches(/\\u000A/)

false

>>> print "\\u000A".matches(/\\u000A/);

true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~"[\u0000-\u0008\u000B\u000C\u000E-\u001F\u007F-\u009F]"

Appears to be working as it should. According to the docs I've seen, the double backslashes shouldn't be required with a slashy string, so I don't know why the compiler's not happy with them.

Comment: lotrepl.appspot.com is perfectly happy with `\u0000` (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240356/groovy-regex-problem/3242087#3242087 )

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems Groovy changed in this regard in the meantime, at least on https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ and a local Groovy shell, `"\n".matches(/\u000A/)` works perfectly fine, evaluating to `true`.

In case you have a similar situation again, just encode the backslash with a unicode escape like in `"\n".matches(/\u005Cu000A/)` as then the unicode escape to character conversion makes it a backslash again and then the sequence for the regex parser is kept.

Another option would be to separate the backslash from the `u` for example by using `"\n".matches(/${'\\'}u000A/)` or `"\n".matches('\\' + /u000A/)`